# XMLDOM.save(Response) do nothing instead of throwing exception

Tags: asp-classic, jscript

Instead of fail with "buffer limit exceeded" error this code works, but do ***absolutely nothing***. Repsonse is empty and there's nothing indicating that something gone wrong.

```
reponseXML = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
...
// responseXML.xml is ~5,6MiB; Response buffer is 4,0MiB.
reponseXML.save(Response);
```

However, next code works fine for all cases I've tested.

```
Response.Write(reponseXML.xml);
```

Comment: **Response** it's a reserved word. Are you sure that you are trying to save the Response Buffer ?????

Comment: Wut? It's built-in asp object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525405(v=vs.90).aspx